# Nested Folders in Windows Several Folders Deep/For Each Container in SSIS

Tags: foreach, ssis

I have multiple text files nested several folders deep.  The first folder (I'll call it MainFolder) has folders delineated by Year, then ProgramCycle, then ProgramName, then ProgramCycleName, then five files in the folders.  It looks like this:

MainFolder > ProgramCycle > ProgramName > ProgramCycleName > files (.txt) files)

I know how to process the files once I get to them.  I believe I need to create several ForEach containers in my SSIS task and use a variable (or perhaps more than one variable) from one ForEach Loop container to the next ForEach Loop container.

There may be a simple solution here, but I am a newbie, and I apologize if this is a silly question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use so many ForEach Loop containers. Open the ForEach loop container, set the value for the 'Folder' as your root directory. Check the box 'Traverse subfolders'. That's about it.